# Failing to load image from File in SFML with C++ as its primary language

Tags: c++, game-development, sfml

I just started learning *how to make games with SFML in c++* but while learning the basic structure of SFML and got to a point where i need to load a texture with sprite i get the error below along with some weird characters only a computer can understand :

```
`Failed to load image "░m:¶=☺./brick.jpg
¢l°ú╕l°i▐▒≈ ♥X☻ ┐╕l°H·╧ú$H·╧ú$╘∙╧ú$£ò╓`£
à]▐▒≈9`▐▒≈☺£
=☺p]▐▒≈▐^▐▒≈α▐▒≈ Γ▐▒≈0<▀▒≈↑<▀▒≈₧]▐▒≈╬`▐▒≈}%ï¡°á╛ú$X¬¬¡°0√  ≡♦0√  ╨♦!`
```

And here's my code snippet :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "Demo Screen");

    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    Texture texture;

    if (!texture.loadFromFile("./brick.jpg"))
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    };

    Sprite sprite;

    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        window.draw(sprite);
        
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Before seeking help here , i tried a few different solutions found in here with chatGPT which include :

- checking if the image is in the directory as the executable file.
- all the properties of the project configuration are all set.
- The image is the correct name including it's extension and it is not corrupted.
- I also tried the absolute path and relative path.
- I also tried by untoggled the hide unknown extensions in the file settings and applied it to all folders.
- I tried also running the program with the debug & the release to.

**Many in the comments have question my environment**

- SFML V2.6.1 ( used the official installer )
- Visual Studio 2022
- MSYS2 13.2.0 ( used to install the MinGW64 compiler with  this pacman command `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain` )
- Windows 11
- Surface Pro 6 ( i develop in it )

**Note** : something stood out when i was debugging the code my self.

The program highlighted something related to `vcruntime140.dll` only when i use the path `./brick.jpg` but when the absolute path is used nothing is thrown except the usual `Failed to load image` but if i use the relative path `./assets/brick.jpg` it return an error of `Unable to load File` with weird symboly.

Comment: The file needs to be in [*the working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is not necessarily the same directory where the executable file is located. How do you run the program?

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the file. If that works and the relative path did not then you know you have an issue with where the working directory is located.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I run the program with debug but i also tried with release which gave the same error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja can you possibly provide step by step or detailed instruction for you statement

Comment: `if (!texture.loadFromFile("/the/full/path/to/the/file/named/brick.jpg"))`

Comment: "checking if the image is in the directory as the executable file" Is not always correct. This depends on how you are running your code. On Visual Studio Community this is the wrong place to put your files unless you modified the debugger settings from the default which is set to `$(ProjectDir)`

Comment: "The image is the correct name including it's extension and it is not corrupted." Can be a problem on MS Windows because the file explorer has a "hide known extensions" option that is enabled by default. This is one of the first settings I disable on Windows as a programmer.

Comment: i tried this solution of `hide known extensions` in the File settings. And @RetiredNinja , i also tried the absolute path , i even open it with the browser and its proper directory and it still returning the same error with the weird symbols.

Comment: I tried many solution and failed to the point of giving up but that's a coward move. Please does anyone how more solutions up their sleeves

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct binaries for your compiler? Remember in most cases for c++ based libraries msvc binaries are not compatible with MinGW. If you are using MinGW I recommend you install MinGW and sfml both using msys2 and don't download sfml binaries.

Comment: Assuming there is not an issue with SFML itself If the absolute path did not work then the path you used is either incorrect or there is an issue with the data or permissions of the file. The garbage error message does make it seem like there could be something else going on with your installation of SFML. What version is it? Where did you get it? What compiler are you using and on what platform?

Comment: I am using SFML : - version 2.6.1 ; I got it on their official webpage ; I am using MinGW-w64 ; Windows 11 & i code on Surface pro 6

Comment: @drescherjm i suspect the same *except* when it comes to load from the file then there's a problem. And before starting to learn SFML , i started learning the basic of c++ so i install MinGW with msys2 with the installer. I also installed SFML with the x64 installer. So i guess we can say i installed them separately.

Comment: When you "run the program with debug", what do you mean by that? What environment (IDE, editor, command-line, OS, etc) are you using? What are the commands, if any, you use to build? What options and flags have you set when building? What options and flags have you set when running? Please ***[edit]*** your question to include all those details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i edited the question as you requested including some details on it , I appreciate your and the others' help in advance.

Comment: I also can't move on to the next lesson because loading the sprites & textures is major.

Comment: Are you compiling this in Visual Studio using the Microsoft compiler or are you doing something different with MinGW and msys? Can you explain the exact steps used to get from source code to executable and exactly how you are running that executable?

Comment: I am also confused at `Visual Studio 2022` and msys2 / MinGW. As the Visual Studio 2022 Community IDE comes with a msvc (Microsoft's compiler). Or are you using VSCode. If you are using VSCode with MinGW, I recommend that you don't download sfml even with the official installer. Instead use pacman to install the proper sfml for the MinGW you installed.